# is there any plugin for spell-checking in SonarQube after version 5.2?

Tags: java, sonarqube, spell-checking, spelling

Is there any spell check plugin for `SonarQube` which can work with current version or 5.6 ?

```
https://github.com/webdizz/sonarqube-spellcheck
```

is unfortunately incompatible since version 5.2

Thanks.

Comment: Questions for off-site resources are ... off-topic here; sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Library for all SonarQube plugins and version compatibility